# Debugging hosting emulator firebase

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-tools

Is it possible to debug hosting emulator inside VS Code for example.
Functions have `--inspect-functions` and that works really good we can attach to it.
Is there something like that in hosting emulator am i missing something?

Thank you and best regards

Comment: The emulators let you debug *your* code that runs inside them. The Firebase Hosting emulator doesn't execute any of *your* code, so there's nothing you can really debug about it. --- If you're having a hard time getting something to work, it's more likely someone can help if you show a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase emulators let you debug *your* code that runs inside them.

The Firebase Hosting emulator doesn't execute any of *your* code, so there's nothing you can really debug about it.

If you connected Firebase Hosting to Cloud Functions or Cloud Run to execute *your* code on the servers, you can debug that code on *those* emulators.